# How to remove reference from a BindingSource in C# Winforms application?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0, bindingsource

This is a C# (v3.0) Winforms problem.

I have a big object that is associated with a BindingSource. When I have done with this object and the BindingSource, I want to remove the reference from the BindingSource so the object can be released. I used BindingSource.Clear(). But after that, in the memory profiler, I can still see the object alive and the only reference is from the BindingSource.lastCurrentItem.

My question is, how should I remove the reference from the BindingSource? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you set `BindingSource.DataSource = null`?

`BindingSource.Clear()` clears all elements in the underlying list (`BindingSource.List`), but doesn't remove the reference to the data source. ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.clear.aspx))

Comment: I have tried setting BindingSource.DataSource = null but the reference still exists, which is wired to me.

Comment: By the way, the BindingSource has a chain. So rootBS.DataSource = bigObject; And later, childBS.DataSource = rootBS; childBS.DataMember = "xxx"; I don't know if this is the case, is there any particular order that I have to follow to remove references of bigObject from both rootBS and childBS. Thanks.